# To convince someone to do something that they do anyways (idiom)

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

In my native language we have an ironic saying: "It is hard to convince a fish to jump into water", which is used when we convince for example an alcoholic to take a drink or an athlete to go jogging. The act itself doesn't have to be easy for the individual, only natural or expected.

Is there a similar saying in English?

Comment: In English, it has been my experience that such ironic/sarcastic statements about the [lack of] difficulty of getting something/somebody to do something (like your fish idiom) would usually include “It’s/that’s **about as** hard **as** …” to signal the irony/sarcasm.  With “about as hard as” added, you can easily create your own phrases, or use some that I’ve heard (“That’s about as hard as convincing/getting a dog to eat meat/chase his tail/chase cats” or “That’s about as hard as convincing/getting a cat to ignore you/chase mice.”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preaching to the choir** means trying to persuade an already convinced audience.  The idiom is based on the idea of a pastor of a church delivering his sermon to the people in the choir, who are presumably already believers.  Generally it's used to mean "you don't have to convince *me*," as in "Hey buddy, you're preaching to the choir here, I'm already voting Democratic this year" (or whatever).

> (idiomatic) Speaking as if to convince a person or group of something which that person or group already believes. Often used to imply that a speaker is addressing the wrong audience or is deliberately addressing a compliant, non-challenging audience.
>
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preach_to_the_choir

Answer (score 0):

***[Preach to the converted](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/preach+to+the+converted)***:

> - to try to persuade people to believe things they already believe (usually in continuous tenses).
>
>   - *There's no need to tell us about the benefits of recycling. You're preaching to the converted*.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: This sounds like the opposite of what the OP is seeking. He suggests that it is *not* hard to persuade the subject to take the action. Your phrase suggests that it *is* hard to get an Eskimo to pay for ice.

Comment: This isn't an edit of your answer, this is a completely new and different answer.

Comment: I had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom ["pushing at an open door"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/push-at-or-against-an-open-door) has that meaning:

> *Definition of push at or against an open door in English:*
>
> Have no difficulty in accomplishing a task:
>    ‘if the management were to tackle this issue, it might find that it was pushing at an open door’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*

For example, "trying to persuade that alcoholic to have a drink was pushing at an open door"...